# Writing php while loop code in a .JS file

Tags: php, javascript, loops

In a JS image slide file script is like this

```
slides :    [           // Slideshow Images
                                            {image : 'images/bgslide/r1.jpg', title : '<h1>Välkommen till Restaurangen SPICE</h1> <p>Bokabord/Beställa Online/ Smaka Gott<br><span></span></p>',},
                                            {image : 'images/bgslide/r2.jpg', title : '<h1>Thai Veg-Tallrik</h1> <p>Blandade Thai veg-rätter med sallad. Helgenserbjudande<br> <span>:89 </span></p>',},
                                            {image : 'images/bgslide/r3.jpg', title : '<h1>Välkommen till Restaurangen SPICE</h1> <p>Bokabord/Beställa Online/ Smaka Gott<br> <span></span> </p>',},
                                            {image : 'images/bgslide/r4.jpg', title : '<h1>Dessert</h1> <p>vaniljglass med körsbär<br><span>:59 </span></p>',}
                                    ],
```

But I want to make this slide with php mysql. want to use while loop. My written loop code is

`slides :    [           // Slideshow Images
            <?php
                $q_f ="SELECT * FROM bgslide order by id" or die($query."<br/>".mysql_error());
                $r_f = mysql_query($q_f);
                $comma='';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_f))
                  {
 ?>
<?php echo $comma; ?>   {image : 'images/bgslide/<?php echo $row["bgimg"]; ?>', title : '<h1><?php echo $row["captitle"]; ?></h1> <p><?php echo $row["capdsc"]; ?><br><span><?php echo $row["price"]; $comma=', '; ?></span></p>',}
                    <?php } ?>
                                        ],` 
And its not working. Can any one help me too solve this problem..?

Answer (score -1):

Just try this-

```
<?php 
    $q_f ="SELECT * FROM bgslide order by id" or die($query."<br/>".mysql_error()); 
    $r_f = mysql_query($q_f); 
    $slide = ''; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_f)) {
        $slide .= "{image : 'images/bgslide/".$row["bgimg"]."', title : '<h1>".$row["captitle"]."</h1> <p>".$row["capdsc"]."<br><span></span></p>',},";
    }
    ?>
slides :    [<?php echo $slide?>],
```

Comment: god have mercy! usage of deprecated mysql functions aswell as not using json_encode($object).

Comment: @ItaiSagi: than suggest the better answer instead giving downvote.